# CMake: how to use INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES with ExternalProject?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add external project as a library to my project using ExternalProject_Add:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        xgboost
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
        GIT_TAG v0.60
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Also, I'm defining library target and adding external project as a dependency:

```
set(XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src")
set(XGBOOST_BINARY_PATH "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost-build")
set(XGBOOST_BINARY_INCLUDE "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/include;${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/dmlc-core/include;${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/rabit/include")
add_library(libxgboost IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libxgboost xgboost)

set_target_properties(libxgboost PROPERTIES
        "IMPORTED_LOCATION" "${XGBOOST_BINARY_PATH}/liblibxgboost.dylib"
        "IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}"
        "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES" "${XGBOOST_BINARY_INCLUDE}"
        )
```

in another CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(somelib STATIC SomeLib.cpp)
target_include_directories(somelib PUBLIC libxgboost)
target_link_libraries(somelib libxgboost)
```

The problem is that cmake INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES doesn't allow to export include dir which does not exist.

Is there any other way to make header files being included automatically for all targets which depend on *libxgboost* ?

**UPDATE:**

Error message:

```
CMake Error in somelib/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "libxgboost" includes non-existent path

    "build/xgboost/src/xgboost/include"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

Comment: Presize error message, please.

Comment: `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES` is deprecated btw. Use `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`. Have you considered using `execute_process()` to call `cmake` (twice) on the ExternalProject CMakeLists.txt then you would have dependencies available at configure time? Alternatively, you could fake the creation of just the dependency directories during CMakeLists.txt configure time.

Comment: That's my plan B, but still wondering if there is a good practice for that

Comment: I faced the same exact issue. Any luck?

Comment: @mchiasson I've added the full CMakeLists.txt, hope it will help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll post the final `CMakeLists.txt` to include xgboost into your project, it might be useful for someone, the solution to the problem above is to create directories during `cmake` configure phase (NOTE: I'm using OSX to build that, so you would need to use `liblibxgboost.so` for GNU/Linux instead of `liblibxgboost.dylib`):

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
        xgboost
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
        GIT_TAG v0.60
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

set(XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src")
set(XGBOOST_BINARY_PATH "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost-build")

set(XGBOOST_LIB_INCLUDE "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/include")
set(DMLC_LIB_INCLUDE "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/dmlc-core/include")
set(RABIT_LIB_INCLUDE "${XGBOOST_PREFIX_PATH}/xgboost/rabit/include")
set(XGBOOST_BINARY_INCLUDE "${XGBOOST_LIB_INCLUDE};${DMLC_LIB_INCLUDE};${RABIT_LIB_INCLUDE}")

# Hack to make it work, otherwise INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will not be propagated
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${XGBOOST_LIB_INCLUDE})
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${DMLC_LIB_INCLUDE})
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${RABIT_LIB_INCLUDE})

add_library(libxgboost IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libxgboost xgboost)

set_target_properties(libxgboost PROPERTIES
        "IMPORTED_LOCATION" "${XGBOOST_BINARY_PATH}/liblibxgboost.dylib"
        "INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES" "${XGBOOST_BINARY_INCLUDE}"
)
```

Comment: I hope CMake will support this better; it seems like a bit of a hack.  Is there no way to handle this with dependencies somehow?  For example, you can set the IMPORTED_LOCATION of a library without it existing. Having INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES be different seems inconsistent.

Comment: @JeffTrull I wish it supports it in a better way. But it's the only way I've found, still, it doesn't mean that it's the only way that exists. I'm new to cmake so I could be missing something here.

Comment: FWIW, `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ...)` is what people came up with on the CMake bug tracker too: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15052

Answer (score 2):

Note that it is possible to combine `FetchContent` and `ExternalProject_Add` to achieve the following:

- `FetchContent` will make the source available at *configure time*, thereby bypassing the issue that the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` doesn't exist.
- `ExternalProject_Add` will use the source downloaded by `FetchContent` to build at *build time*

Here is an example building `libpqxx`:

```
include(FetchContent)
include(ExternalProject)

find_package(PostgreSQL)

# Using FetchContent means we will download libpqxx at configure-time

FetchContent_Declare(libpqxx_ext
    GIT_REPOSITORY
        https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx
    GIT_TAG
        tags/7.4.1
    )

FetchContent_GetProperties(libpqxx_ext)

if(NOT libpqxx_ext_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(libpqxx_ext)
endif()

set(LIB_PQXX_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/libpqxx_ext-src)

# Build libpqxx

ExternalProject_Add(libpqxx_ext
    SOURCE_DIR
        ${libpqxx_ext_SOURCE_DIR}
    PREFIX
        ext
    BINARY_DIR
        build
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DSKIP_BUILD_TEST=on
    INSTALL_COMMAND
        ""
    BUILD_ALWAYS
        OFF
    )

set(LIB_PQXX_BUILD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build/src)

# Make the libpxqq artifacts available to our project

add_library(libpqxx STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(libpqxx
    PROPERTIES

    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
        ${LIB_PQXX_SRC_DIR}/include
    IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${LIB_PQXX_BUILD_DIR}/libpqxx.a
    INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES
        ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(libpqxx libpqxx_ext)
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, better than creating CMake folders. This also avoids a fetch with every build.