# CMake Error: Remove failed on file System Error: Device or resource busy

Tags: cmake, cgal, msys2

When trying to `cmake` a CGAL example, I get

```
CMake Error: Remove failed on file:
/cgal/example/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_9e180.exe: System Error: Device or resource busy
```

Working under Win10 + Msys2.

CGAL was obtained via `pacman` (`local/mingw-w64-x86_64-cgal 4.13-1`).

Since I did not find the CGAL examples in any Msys2 package, 
it was copied from file `/usr/share/doc/libcgal13/examples.tar.gz`, which was obtained in an Ubuntu system with

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcgal-demo
```

The example is [`reconstruction_surface_mesh.cpp`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction_2reconstruction_surface_mesh_8cpp-example.html) from `examples/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction`.

I wouldn't know if the origin of the error is specific to my `CMakeLists.txt`, or else.

*Related, but AFAICT not providing the answer*:

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2010-November/012619.html

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17566

https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/issues/634

[CMake: how to use INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES with ExternalProject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516209/cmake-how-to-use-interface-include-directories-with-externalproject/47358004#47358004)

https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=CMake+Error+in+CMakeLists.txt%3A+++Imported+target+includes+non-existent+path+in+its+INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.++Possible+reasons+include

Comment: Have you tried it in Cygwin, WSL, or a native Windows environment?  It sounds like CMake is trying to delete a test executable before it finishes running.  Windows doesn't allow that, but Posix does.  I don't know how Msys behaves in this regard.

Comment: No, I did not try that. I will se if I can get such a system.